# Using linear regression to compute continuously compounded growth rates

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

I'm exploring the differences between compound annual growth rates and continuously compounded growth rates. The World Bank [seems to prefer](http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/DATASTATISTICS/0,,contentMDK:20452034~menuPK:64133152~pagePK:64133150~piPK:64133175~theSitePK:239419,00.html) using continuously compounded rates calculated using linear regression (when the data allow it). I set up the following example in R to illustrate the differences between a few methods and was surprised at just how different the linear regression result was.

My question: Why is the result using linear regression so different from the other methods and what does that say about the appropriate circumstances under which to use linear regression for calculating growth rates?

Methods to solve for r:

1) Geometric mean:

```
r = [(1+r1)*(1+r2)*...*(1+rn)]^(1/n) - 1
```

2) "Standard" CAGR (same as 1):

```
final_value = initial_value*((1+r)^num_time_periods)
```

3) continuously compounded using PERT formula:

```
final_value = initial_value*(e^(r*num_time_periods))
```

4) estimating log-lin model:

```
ln(value) = B0 + B1*time_period + u
```

and backing out the annualized growth: r = (e^B1)-1

R code:

```
#Sample values
v <- c(22,13,17,19,22,50,30)

#########################################################################
# Concept 1 - Compound annual growth rate (CAGR)                        #
#########################################################################

#Method 1: computing geometric mean
vc <- v[2:length(v)]/v[1:length(v)-1]
r1 <- ((vc[1]*vc[2]*vc[3]*vc[4]*vc[5]*vc[6])^(1/6))-1

#Method 2: solving formula, final = initial*((1+r)^time_periods)
r2 <- ((v[7]/v[1])^(1/6))-1

#CAGR methods 1 & 2 produce the same result (difference is negligible)
r1-r2

#####################################################################
# Concept 2 - Continuously compounded growth rates                  #
#####################################################################

#Method 3: solving PERT formula: final = initial*(e^(rate*time_periods))
r3 <- log(v[7]/v[1])/6

#not surprisingly, method 3 produces a slightly different result from the CAGR
r3-r1

#Method 4: log-linear regression, ln(value) = B0 + B1*time_period + u 
df <- data.frame(val=log(v), period=1:7)

#run regression
reg <- lm(val~period, df)

#growth rate = (e^B1)-1
r4 <- exp(reg$coefficients[["period"]])-1

#the growth rate given by the regression is very different from others
r4-r3
```

Comment: It might be better to give the formulas you are using in the text to get a wider audience as otherwise people have to do a code review to see whether the issue is related to the methods or to your implementation of them.

Comment: The differences are larger than you think.  This article,   https://ssrn.com/abstract=2828744 discusses the differences and https://ssrn.com/abstract=2656681 discusses the econometric issues.